# Explanation of HEX value representation and Endianess

Tags: c, hex, endianness

I was working on a script to basically output some sample data as a binary blob.
I'm a new intern in the software field and vaguely remember the idea of endianness.

I realize that the most significant bits for big-endian starts at the top and works down the memory block.

If I have 0x03000201 and the data is being parsed to output 0 1 2, how does this happen and what is being done to make that work in terms of bits, bytes, etc.

I am wondering, in the example posted below, how the numbers are extracted to form 0 1 2 when printing out the data stored in the variables.

For example: I am creating a couple lines of the binary blob using this file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
        FILE *file;
        int  buffer = 0x03000201;
        int  buffer2= 0x010203;
        file = fopen("test.bin", "wb");

        if (file != NULL)
        {
                fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, file);
                fwrite(&buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), 1, file);
                fclose(file);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I then created a Python script to parse this data:

## Info About Parse

```
import struct
with open('test.bin','rb') as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(4)
        if not data: break
        var1, var2, var3 = struct.unpack('=BHB', data)
        print(var1, var2, var3)
```

Comment: Your question is absolutely unclear! what do you mean with _parsed to output_?

Comment: Why not just use wikipedia - this is simple stuff

Comment: What is simple to some, may not be simple to others. Hence the idea of a community of people to help others.

Comment: Why not read the pages on hex and what is difficult in understanding that bytes may be interpreted in different orde

Comment: Have you **actually** tried to read anything related? This is no tutorial site. The question is off-topic.

Comment: What exactly your question is?

Comment: I was really just looking to understand how 0x0300020 when read 2 bytes at a time and reprinted yields 0 1 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big or little endianness defines how to interpret a sequence of bytes longer than one byte and how to store those in memory. Wikipedia will help you with that.

> I was really just looking to understand how 0x0300020 when read 2
>   bytes at a time and reprinted yields 0 1 2.

You don't read 2 bytes at a time, you read 4 bytes: `data = f.read(4)`

```
f.read(size) reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string.
```

You unpack data using =BHB - byte, 2 bytes, byte. Endianness comes into play only when you unpack data, all other IO calls in your code deal with byte sequences.

Experiment with [unpack() Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) You may also look at file data with a HEX editor of your choice.

And if, after your research, you have a concrete question, ask here.

Comment: Thank you, this was a lot of help.